# there is evident a serious and purposeful rekindling of confidence

Tags: expletive-pronoun

> *Within us, the people of the United States, there is evident a serious and purposeful rekindling of confidence.*

This sentence is from "Jimmy Carter inaugural address: Jan. 20, 1977" shown [here](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/jimmy-carter-inaugural-address-1977/).

What does the there-clause mean, and how common is this type of construction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of construction is not common in normal colloquial speech. It’s very formal-sounding. It has the same meaning as

> Within us, the people of the United States, a serious and purposeful rekindling of confidence is evident.

or

> Within us, the people of the United States, it is evident that there is a serious and purposeful rekindling of confidence.

*there* in the original sentence is being used as a pronoun. This is similar to saying *there exists*- that phrase is used in [predicate logic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification) and sometimes other contexts but it always sounds very formal.

Comment: Can you put 'evident' at the end? _...there is a serious and purposeful rekindling of confidence evident._

Comment: @listeneva yes you can, that’s another way to rephrase this sentence.